# Follow path algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

Could you give me a link for beginner tutorial on fast follow path algorithm ?

Path should include curves and will be hard-codded in application.
I don't want to make curves totally random. They could be half or quater circles with  different diameter.

Entities should follow this path within a given distance (on a line that is orthogonal to path)

Entities are represented as boxes in this world. Each time they update they get time delta argument that is multiplied by speed.

**This is what i want to achieve.**

[image]

Thanks

Comment: We need much more detail - what are you doing? how are you representing space it your game?

Comment: I tried, it came up with some results. But lot of these tutorial were hard to grasp. So if you know good tutorial for beginners.

Comment: I'm sure you could use something like a PID controller to trace a path for each enemy that has a different navigation system (although I suspect it's the same for all enemies) and then us that path for all relevant enemies. That should give you a nice, smooth path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know in tower defense games like the one you linked, the creep path is always static based on the map. I'm willing to bet money it's literally hard coded in the map itself as a series of curves which you can interpolate over as needed.

Comment: Yes thats it. So, i should make anchor points and then interpolates between them ? What interpolating method should i use ? I read about cosine interpolation, they say it should be pretty fast. Do you think it is the right choice ?

Comment: Linear interpolation should be fine as long as the points are equidistant from eachother, but try em both and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can google for A*, Dijkstra algorithm, Bellman-Ford algorithm, Floyd and Warshall... there are plenty of tutorials - the most commonly used in simple games is propably A*.
[Wikipedia about Pathfinding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding)

Comment: I don't know if A* suits me. The path is given by lines and curves. I just to follow it within a given distance.

Comment: @jellyfication are you given the path and just want to follow it, or does your program need to come up with the path first?

Comment: @Jack Edmonds I am given with the path.